# .AllowUserInteraction doesn't work for UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer, animatewithduration

Applying an animation to a UIImageView prevents interaction during the animation, despite including .allowUserInteraction as an option. The view seems to only respond near the end of animation. I have spent countless hours researching this to no avail. Other posts suggest changing the alpha value, but that seems to only apply to buttons. (UIImageView connected to @IBAction via UIPanGestureRecognizer).

```
@IBAction func panAction(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {

            recognizer.view?.center.y += 300

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: ImageView is not affects user interaction you can set it on the objects which can be pressed / tapped(i.e. Button, Cell, CollectionView)

Answer (score 0):

ImageView is not affects user interaction you can set it on the objects which can be pressed / tapped(i.e. Button, Cell, CollectionView).

You have to set it on pan gesture/ You have to disable pan gesture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please clarify, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Yeah sure. What clarification you need??

Comment: I want to be able to stop the view from animating and move it around. But I need pan gesture for the functions recognizer provides. So what do you suggest?

Comment: Try with taking one button on that imageView. And then Put **.AllowUserInteraction** in ButtonAction But not on an ImageView But on Button Itself.

Comment: Image views do allow user interaction, but I tried swapping it with a button which made no difference